# How to justify the uniqueness and existence of this sequence by Transfinite Recursion Theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, ordinals

For $F \subseteq \Bbb R$, the *derived set* of $F$, denoted by $F'$, is the set of all limit points of $F$.

> Prove that there exists a unique transfinite sequence $\langle F_\alpha \rangle_{\alpha \in \rm{Ord}}$ of subsets of $\Bbb R$ such that
>
> $$\begin{align}
> F_0 &= F \subseteq \Bbb R\\
> F_{\alpha+1} &= (F_{\alpha})' \space \text{ for all } \alpha \in \rm{Ord}\\
> F_{\alpha} &= \bigcap_{\xi < \alpha} F_{\xi} \text{ for all limit ordinal } \alpha
> \end{align}$$

Does my attempt look fine or contain logical flaws/gaps? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

Let $V$ be the class of all sets. We define a class function $\mathcal G: V \to V$ by $$ \mathcal G(x)=\begin{cases} x' &\text{ if } x \subseteq \Bbb R\\ \bigcap \rm{ran}(x) & \text{ if }x \text{ is a non-empty function}\\\emptyset & \text { otherwise } \end{cases}$$

By *Transfinite Recursion Theorem*, there exists a unique class function $\mathcal F:\rm{Ord} \to V$ such that

- $\mathcal F(0)=F$
- $\mathcal F(\alpha+1)=\mathcal G(\mathcal F(\alpha))$  for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$
- $\mathcal F(\alpha)=\mathcal G(\mathcal F\restriction\alpha)$  for all limit $\alpha\neq 0$

> 1. $\mathcal F(\alpha) \subseteq \Bbb R$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$

We have $\mathcal F(0)=F \subseteq \Bbb R$.

If $\mathcal F(\alpha) \subseteq \Bbb R$, then $\mathcal G(\mathcal F(\alpha))=(\mathcal F(\alpha))'\subseteq \Bbb R$ by the definition of $\mathcal G$. So $\mathcal F(\alpha+1)=\mathcal G(\mathcal F(\alpha))\subseteq \Bbb R$.

If $\mathcal F(\xi) \subseteq \Bbb R$ for all $\xi < \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. It follows from the construction of $\mathcal G$ that $\mathcal F(\alpha)=\mathcal G(\mathcal F\restriction\alpha)=\bigcap \rm{ran}(\mathcal F\restriction\alpha)=\bigcap_{\xi < \alpha} \mathcal F(\xi) \subseteq \Bbb R$. Thus $\mathcal F(\alpha) \subseteq \Bbb R$.

> 2. $\mathcal F(\alpha+1) = (\mathcal F(\alpha))'$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$

We have $\mathcal F(\alpha+1)=\mathcal G(\mathcal F(\alpha))$. From **1.**, we have $\mathcal F(\alpha) \subseteq \Bbb R$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$. Then $\mathcal G(\mathcal F(\alpha)) = (F(\alpha))'$ by the construction of $\mathcal G$. Thus $\mathcal F(\alpha+1) = (\mathcal F(\alpha))'$.

> 3. If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $\mathcal F(\alpha) = \bigcap_{\xi < \alpha} \mathcal F(\xi)$

Since $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, $\mathcal F(\alpha)=\mathcal G(\mathcal F\restriction\alpha) =\bigcap \rm{ran}(\mathcal F\restriction\alpha)$ by the construction of $\mathcal G$. We have $\bigcap \rm{ran}(\mathcal F\restriction\alpha)=\bigcap_{\xi < \alpha} \mathcal F(\xi)$. Thus $\mathcal F(\alpha) = \bigcap_{\xi < \alpha} \mathcal F(\xi)$.

We define sequence $\langle F_\alpha \rangle_{\alpha \in \rm{Ord}}$ by $F_\alpha=\mathcal F(\alpha)$. It follows that

$$\begin{align}
F_0 &= F\\
F_{\alpha+1} &= (F_{\alpha})' \space \text{ for all } \alpha \in \rm{Ord}\\
F_{\alpha} &= \bigcap_{\xi < \alpha} F_{\xi} \text{ for all limit ordinal } \alpha
\end{align}$$

Comment: We do not say "the unique existence". The common and correct expression is "the existence and uniqueness".

Comment: Thank you @AndrésE.Caicedo! That's my bad.

Comment: By the way, it is worrisome that you are still asking for feedback on routine questions such as this and that you feel the need to include such a mountain of details.

Comment: Hi @AndrésE.Caicedo. Honestly, I am self-studying by now. It will be great if you give me some advice on how to self-study.

Comment: Exercise: Prove there exists $\alpha \in \omega_1$ such that $F'_{\alpha}=F_{\alpha}.$

Comment: Hi @DanielWainfleet, I have presented a proof for $(F_{\alpha})'=F_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in \omega_1$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3115861/every-uncountable-closed-set-contains-a-perfect-subset). If you don't mind, please have a chek on it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looks OK. There are also other methods.

Comment: Thank you for your verification @DanielWainfleet!